# Namespace for XMLList on JMSSerializerBundle

Tags: xml, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I'm trying to create a XML using JMSSerializerBundle, and this XML must have some nodes with namespace (please see gist linked below for full code example) but I get a node with wrong namespace, and this wrong namespace is repeated even in parent node (XMLList).

Have you ever faced a problem like this?
Can you please help me figuring out how to solve this issue?

Thanks a lot.

code example - [1]: https://gist.github.com/coolder/38157850a45cfef7ff22

Comment: You should add the (relevant) code parts to the question.

Comment: what do you mean for "relevant"? php code or resulting xml?

Comment: Most probably both. Without the extra parts (but please keep the link to the original gist). (Sorry I am not familiar with Symphony2 (just reviewed your question and seen the link with code behind and no code in question).)